# Knockout mapping replace empty properties with other properties

Tags: knockout.js

I want to return a JSON data using knockout and DisplayName is sometimes have empty string. If it's empty, I want to replace it with the Name but I don't want to use a create: option because I don't want to map each node.

```
            'DisplayName': {
            update: function (options) {
                if (options.data !== "") {
                    return options.data;
                    console.log(options);
                }
                else {
                    return options.Name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ew48r0pd/1/

So the result I expected should be 
Admin1
Joe
Robert
Tim
Admin5

Comment: After looking at the console log, I found the parent object but when I display it, it show as a function. However when I add () at the end, it's saying the options.parent.Name is not a function, although it's working fine on the updated jsFiddle. Here is the updated jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ew48r0pd/3

Any idea why it won't work on mine

Comment: yes fiddle looks good in real its should work fine too unless you making any type errors .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take the http://jsfiddle.net/ew48r0pd/3 as the answer.

```
var Item = {            
        'FullName': {
            create: function (options) {
                if (options.DisplayName !== "") {
                    return options.DisplayName;
                    console.log(options);
                }
                else {
                    return options.Name;
                }
            }
        },

        'DisplayName': {
            update: function (options) {
                if (options.data !== "") {
                    return options.data;

                }
                else {
                    return options.parent.Name();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```